# How do the tests work for spring boot apps

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to understand spring boot and all the work with it. At the moment I'm struggling with integration tests so I went to see [spring-boot-samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples). I started to look at [spring-boot-sample-testng](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-testng)

In this integration test sample I don't see any reference to SampleTestNGApplication class, where the main method is.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class SampleTestNGApplicationTests extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testHome() {
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = this.restTemplate.getForEntity("/", String.class);
        assertThat(entity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK);
        assertThat(entity.getBody()).isEqualTo("Hello World");
    }

}
```

How does it know that the main method is in SampleTestNGApplication class.

Comment: this might help https://blog.ccbill.com/spring-boot-and-context-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in [SpringBootTest doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html). I should have paid my attention to

> Automatically searches for a @SpringBootConfiguration when nested @Configuration is not used, and no explicit classes are specified.

My main class is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which is a configuration annotation.